# Angular & Spring Boot : File Name issue

Tags: angular, spring-boot, header

when i get the file from the database (mysql) the file name shows like he's encrypting. so my problem is to   show the real file's name on the onglet.

photos below to make things more clear.

> this is my method on Angular:

```
    GetById(id: number) {
        this.uploadService.getFile(id).subscribe((res) => {
          this.retrieveResonse = res;
          this.base64Data = this.retrieveResonse.fileContent;

    var blob = new Blob([this._base64ToArrayBuffer(this.base64Data)], {
              type: "application/pdf",
            });


            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            this.retrievedFile = window.open(url, this.retrieveResonse.fileName);
}

_base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    const binary_string = window.atob(this.base64Data);
    const len = binary_string.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
  }
```

> Upload Service .ts

```
export class UploadFileService {
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/gp";
  OnUpload(selectedFile: File, tag: string, dep: string): Observable<any> {
    const uploadImageData = new FormData();
    uploadImageData.append("file", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
    uploadImageData.append("tag", tag);
    uploadImageData.append("dep", dep);

    //Make a call to the Spring Boot Application to save the image
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/gp/do", uploadImageData, {
      observe: "response",
    });
  }
```

> the template which contains the files

```html
<div id="pricing-table" class="clear" data-aos="fade-right">
  <div class="sel">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" style="left: -160px;">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          [(ngModel)]="SearchTag"
          (input)="Search()"
          style="margin: 20px;"
        />
        <div id="toggle" style="left: 450px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div
    class="plan"
    *ngFor="
      let file of filtered | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p }
    "
  >
    <h3></h3>

    <ul>
      <li><b>Name: </b> {{ file.nom }}</li>
      <li><b>Type: </b> {{ file.type }}</li>
      <li><b>Departement: </b>{{ file.departement }}</li>
      <li><b>Tag: </b>{{ file.tag }}</li>
      <button
        class="btn"
        style="background-color: #09c0a3;"
        (click)="GetById(file.id)"
      >
        Ouvrir
      </button>
      <button
        class="btn"
        style="background-color: #09c0a3;"
        (click)="Remember(file.id)"
      >
        Remember
      </button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<pagination-controls
  (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)"
  (pageBoundsCorrection)="onPageChange($event)"
  style="float: right;"
></pagination-controls>
```

so i think the problem is on angular that's why i didn't any code from the backend.
THANK YOU GUYS.

[example: i want to open this file which has name "Cert20417610441"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWPRn.png)

[Once i opened it, his name changed with an other complicated name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36O7w.png)

Comment: Can you show us the code of the page where you list all the uploaded files?

Comment: @Tecnogirl its done

Comment: Are you using Router in your angular application?

Answer (score 1):

The weird URL comes from these lines:

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

window.open(url, ...)
```

Instead of using a client-side generated hash, try to have the server return an id of the newly uploaded file whenever you upload a file.

Then, on the list page, when a user clicks a file, it should just redirect to the details page of the file, using that ID.

example: `/files/ID_OF_THE_FILE_RETURNED_FROM_THE_SERVER`

Finally, on the details page, you just read the URL and get the ID from it. With the ID, you do a request to the server to get all the file details (including the filename) and you display them on the page.

Comment: When you upload a file, the server should save the uploaded file and associate an ID to it. Then send that ID to the client as the response.

Comment: i got you thank you, but my problem is when i display the file like pdf ,vidéo.. etc so i want it shows with his real name , i tried using iframe but it doesn't work.. otherwise the file details is working as expected